# Create Json array of strings without key through data class in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am creating one of json request object through 'data' class of kotlin. I stuck on a point where I have to create a JSON Array of strings without keys as, below:

```
"filters": {
                "abc": [{
                    "key1": "exRKxYXS5uAjW8hTs",
                    "key2": ["Premium"]
                }],
                "genders": ["MALE", "FEMALE"],
                "def": ["en", "fr"]
            }
```

Here I stuck on genders and def jsonarrays in which I have to put only strings, but how can we create its data classes in kotlin. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is not a valid json format

Comment: Genders is a type of List<String>. Same applies for def and key2.

Answer (score 0):

Use jsonschema2pojo.com to auto generate the correct classes.

Response Class

```
class Response {
    @SerializedName("filters")
    @Expose
    var filters: Filters? = null
}
```

Filters Class

```
class Filters {
    @SerializedName("abc")
    @Expose
    var abc: List<Abc>? = null

    @SerializedName("genders")
    @Expose
    var genders: List<String>? = null

    @SerializedName("def")
    @Expose
    var def: List<String>? = null
}
```

Abc class

```
class Abc {
    @SerializedName("key1")
    @Expose
    var key1: String? = null

    @SerializedName("key2")
    @Expose
    var key2: List<String>? = null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create corresponding data classes as follow:

```
//Response data class
data class Response(
    val filters: Filters?
)

//Filters data class
data class Filters(
    val abc: Abc,
    val genders: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val def: List<String> = emptyList()
)

//Abc data class
data class Abc(
    val key1: String?,
    val key2: String?
)
```

You do not have to use **@SerializedName** as long as you keep the variable names as same as key name.